# Abrir modal de botão dinâmico carregado via ajax

Tags: ajax

Estou com dificuldades para abrir um modal por meio de um botão carregado dinamicamente via ajax.

O seguinte código jquery abaixo abre o modal normalmente, considerando que o botão a ser clicado não foi carregado dinamicamente.

```
$('#idDivModal5').on('click', '.btn-cancelar-contrato', function(){   

// codigo aqui 

});
```

Uma vez que eu gerei os botões via ajax, enviando-os para a minha div resultado, os botões já não mais funcionaram.

Código HTML:

```
<div id=resultado></div>
```

Inclui a div resultado no jquery, conforme mostrado abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
$('#resultado#idDivModal5').on('click', '.btn-cancelar-contrato', function()    
{   

// codigo aqui 

});
```

Segue abaixo o codigo atual:

```
 $('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
   if(remote) {
    $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
 });
```

Requisição ajax:

```
$.ajax({
              type  : "POST",
              url   : "envia-buscar-contrato",
              data  : {var_radio:var_radio,var_valor:var_valor},
              datatype : 'html',
              success: function(data) {         

                    $("#form-buscar :input").prop("disabled", false);           
                    $('.bloquear2').hide();                     
                    $('#resultado').show(); 
                    $("#resultado").slideDown();
                    $("#resultado").html(data);
              }
            });          

 });
```

Esqueleto da modal idDivModal5:

```
<div id="idDivModal5" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Botão retornado via ajax:

```
<div id="resultado">
<a class="botao-form" href='#idDivModal5' role='button' 
data-toggle='modal'                                                               
data-load-remote='cancelar-contrato/<?php echo $codigo_contrato;?>'
 data-remote-target='#idDivModal5 .modal-content' 
aria-hidden='true'>Cancelar contrato</a>
</div>
```

Lembrando que, quando o botão acima não é carregado via ajax, o mesmo abre a modal idDivmodal5 normalmente. A partir do momento em que eu retorno o botão via ajax, ele não abre. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Posta o teu código fonte por favor.

Comment: Vou postar o codigo.

Comment: o botão precisa ser carregado dentro do `$(document)`, pro código ter certeza que o trecho existe.

Comment: Como que ficaria Wilian?

Comment: Obrigado Wiliam. Substitui o  $('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) { pelo $(document).on('click', '[data-load-remote]', function(e) {
e funcionou =D.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Gabriel Rodrigues mencionou, seu botão não está no DOM

uma alternativa é:

```
$(document).on('click', 'classDoBotão', function(){
    // codigo aqui
});
```

Explicando de forma simples, o jquery agora vai procurar na página todos os botões com a **classe** ou **id** que você passar dentro do segundo parâmetro, e executar a sua função

Comment: tive mesmo problemas recentemente no trabalho e esta solução funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é que o button não foi carregado no dom no momento em que você foi criar o seletor, então ele ainda não existe, para contornar este problema você pode utilizar a documentação do bootstrap.

Em Modal você pode utilizar o evento `show.bs.modal` que é quando os elementos da modal já foram carregados.

Um Exemplo disto seria:

```
$('#idDivModal5').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $(".btn-cancelar-contrato").on('click',function(){
       // Modal disponivel e com click funcionando.
   });
})
```

Da para fazer um callback do evento load que vai funcionar tbm.